# Unable to view images generated via allure jasmine reports

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, jasmine, allure

Pre-reqs: allurejasmine

I'm able to take screenshots of failed testcases with below code and png image file is also getting created with xml.

But, I'm unable to view the png file when I double click on the image file.

**Issue: Message in wpv thrown as - It looks like we don't support this file format.**

In paint, it shows this bitmap not supported.

Please suggest.

```
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
 allure.createAttachment('Screenshot', function () {
     return new Buffer(png, 'base64')
      }, 'image/png')();
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
const pngFile = await browser.takeScreenshot();
allure.attachment(screenshotname, Buffer.from(pngFile, 'base64'), ContentType.PNG);
```

ContentType.PNG = 'image/png'

Comment: Thank you. But I get an error ContentType not defined.

Comment: No idea which version you use, this is enum. so you can add it as string 'image/png'

Comment: I tried passing as enum but didn't work.,same error ContentType not defined. I'm using jasmine-allure-reporter as npm pack on ES6.

Comment: seems you dont understand enum, but as i said type it as string